# How to add an system permission in gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I want to add

```
"<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_NETWORK_POLICY"/>" 

but it hints that :

**permission is only granted to system apps..... **
```

and I can't build a apk file in out directory.

But I heard of that ,the newest gradle will support this kind of signature protect level permission declared in manifest?

Is there any info about this change ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest gradle have already support this , and just update the gradle will solve this problem.